# Random rotation on child particles?

Tags: particles, hair

Is there a way to have a random rotation on child hair particles? I know you can have random size, but if there's a way to randomize rotation as well that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Random rough" parameter of the children seems the only one that affects individual children without too much correlation between them¹. Unfortunately though, it inevitably affects sizes too. Also, it can't be constrained to the normal axis (in case you needed it):

[image]

<sup>*3 hair particles, 4 children each*</sup>

A real "random rotation" doesn't exist for children specifically.

¹ *(if "Size" is small enough)*